# DNS lookup slow in browser for local PC

Tags: domain-name-system

Hey, I changed my web application to use my computer name instead of the IP. Since then, the DNS lookup is very slow for 1 out of 3 pages (takes 3 seconds average). Right now, I use the default system settings for proxies. This happens in all browsers.

Here's what it looks like in Firebug.

[image]

How can I fix this? Also, what changes should be made for using computer names for all my network also not just this PC I'm using? I'm using Windows 7 64-bit. Thanks.

Edit: Here's my hosts file:

```
 127.0.0.1       localhost
 alex-pc         localhost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local host file should look like this:

```
127.0.0.1      localhost
127.0.0.1      alex-pc
```

To have other PCs connect to alex-pc you need to add a DNS A record on your router (if it supports it) to point to your PCs local LAN address.  Or add alex-pc into all your PCs hosts file. If your router does not support it.  Setup a small DNS server on a computer and point all your PCs to that computer for DNS queries.  Or change the DNS server in your DHCP settings and release/renew your other PCs. There is not enough details in your question to give more a more accurate fix.